# Can't send ETH to smart contract with Ganache: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I'm having issues sending ETH to an extremely basic smart contract. Here's the smart contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.9;

contract hodl {
  
  uint num;
  uint value;
    
  constructor() {
      num = 69;
      value = 0;
  }
  
  event showNum(uint num);
  event seeSender(address addy, uint value);

  fallback() external payable {
    emit seeSender(msg.sender, msg.value);
    emit showNum(num);
    num += 1;
  }

  function printNum() public returns (uint y){
    emit showNum(num);
    return num;
  }

  function printValue() public returns (uint y){
    return value;
  }

}
```

Here's the deployment code if it matters (file name is 2_deploy_contract.js):

```
const hodl = artifacts.require("hodl.sol");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(hodl);
};
```

Here's the output from my terminal:

```
truffle(ganache)> c = await hodl.deployed()
undefined
truffle(ganache)> c.sendTransaction({from: ‘0x40Fdb0DceC71c8e3b414FB04351C9eDd45116120’, value: ‘1000000000000000'})
evalmachine.<anonymous>:0
c.sendTransaction({from: ‘0x40Fdb0DceC71c8e3b414FB04351C9eDd45116120’, value: ‘1000000000000000'})
                         

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
truffle(ganache)>
```

Comment: In javascript to delimit string you can use single quotes `'` or double quotes `"`. The character you are using isn't the correct one `‘`.

Comment: That doesn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: If you got the same error it means there is another quote that has to be replaced. If you got a different error then you can edit the question to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `const hodl = require('hodl.sol');`

Be:

`const hodl = require('hodl');`

Comment: I think either one is fine

Comment: did you try it? cuz you're supposed to import the contract name not the file name

Answer (score 0):

So I'm super dumb and realized I wasn't sending enough WEI to notice a change in the accounts value. That was the issue.